# How echo command use to interact with device files?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

I've seen this command:
`echo 0x1> /dev/uio0`
It is used to clear the interrupt in a device.
uio0 is the device file created for hardware device.
It is created by adding generic-uio platform to the device-tree.

But how echoing 0x1 to uio0 is clearing the interrupt?

Comment: `how` is a broad question. Are you interested in the exact kernel code that is executed? About echo code? About `>` redirection? exact machine code that is executed? Exact memory address or line that is set? It's just `if (byte_written_to_uio0 == 1) then do_some_machine_code_to_clear_the_interrupt()`, what _exactly_ are you interested in? What research did you do? The driver documentation is available at https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.12/driver-api/uio-howto.html , the kernel input of uio driver at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/uio/uio.c#L620 . What platform you on?

Comment: as i see it, the command is redirecting 0x1 to that device, but what is it mean? to what register in uio 0x1 is going? i build linux on cortex cpu upon fpga design (Xilinx zynq-7000). fpga contain memory-mapped hardware with interrupt. In /proc/interrupt i see my uio0 device, but interrupt trigger does not increase the counting unless i run the aforementioned echo command. so I'm trying to understand the mechanism behind this interrupt.

Comment: "Redirection" means that "standard output" of program "echo" is "connected" to `/dev/uio0` path. So `write` system call of program "echo" to standard output goes to `/dev/uio0` path. On the other side, a kernel function is executed on `write` syscall, which executes a function inside the kernel that was used by the driver to register `/dev/uio0` path. And that kernel function executes some logic. `to what register` That just depends on the exact kernel function that is executed. For that, you have to give the exact platform and kernel version and devices you have, to determine what driver

Comment: I'm using kernel 5.4.       Platform is cortex A9 on Xilinx zynq 7000 board. Is that what you mean by platform?

Comment: @KamilCuk, please use _latest_ or non-ancient versions of the kernel when pointing out to the code on Elixir. v4.12 smells like a rotten corpse.

Comment: Hi. Can you help me answer my issue? I am trying to understand how 'echo' command is clearing the interrupt in /dev/uio0 device in linux

Comment: Try prefacing your shell command with the **strace** command. That will show you what happens on the user-side to perform your command. Search for the appropriate **open()** and **write()** syscalls that pertain to the device in question.